# Javascript function stops working when adding a second parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following, single parameter JS function which hides/shows an html table and works correctly with one small exception - I need to click twice in order for the desired effect to show:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display != 'none')
            e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'table';
    }
```

Now, when I add a second parameter and extend the function to toggle between two img source paths, it no longer works. Firebug console does not provide any error message or other clue:

```
function toggle_visibility(id, arrow) 
    {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       var i = document.getElementById(arrow);
       if(e.style.display != 'none')
          e.style.display = 'none';
          i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhiteRight.bmp';
       else
          e.style.display = 'table';
          i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhite.bmp';
    }
```

The html element I call the function from presents itself as follows:

```
<tr id="trigger" class="toggle" onclick="toggle_visibility('collapsible1', 'img1')">
```

...

The element for the second parameter:

```
<td id="triggerArrow"><img id="img1" src="img/arrowDownWhiteRight.bmp"></td>
```

The element to be hidden/shown (default is "display: none")

```
<table class="collapsible" id="collapsible1">
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use blocks:

```
function toggle_visibility(id, arrow) 
{
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var i = document.getElementById(arrow);
   if(e.style.display != 'none') {                 // <== {
      e.style.display = 'none';
      i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhiteRight.bmp';
   } else {                                        // <== } and {
      e.style.display = 'table';
      i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhite.bmp';
   }                                               // } <==
}
```

In JavaScript, as in most languages syntactically derived from B (C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript...), indentation is completely ignored, and only **one** statement following a control structure like `if` or `while` or `else` is attached to that control structure; so attach more than one statement to them, you use the *block statement* ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)) `{ ... }` to group the statements together.

So:

```
if (condition)
    doThis();
    doThat();   // Misleading indentation, doThat *always* runs
```

is really

```
if (condition)
    doThis();
doThat();
```

where adding a block makes both calls depend on the condition:

```
if (condition) {
    doThis();
    doThat();   // Only happens if the condition is true now
}
```

The location of the `{` and `}` (on the same line, on their own line, etc.) is completely up to you, a matter of style. The style I've shown in the first code block above is very, very common, but based on where you put the `{` for your function, you may prefer this other style which is also common (although more common in other B-derived languages than in JavaScript):

```
function toggle_visibility(id, arrow) 
{
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var i = document.getElementById(arrow);
   if(e.style.display != 'none')
   {
      e.style.display = 'none';
      i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhiteRight.bmp';
   }
   else
   {
      e.style.display = 'table';
      i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhite.bmp';
   }
}
```

Doesn't matter either way, does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute 2 or more statements after an if, use curly braces to group them:

```
function toggle_visibility(id, arrow){
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var i = document.getElementById(arrow);
  if(e.style.display != 'none'){
    e.style.display = 'none';
    i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhiteRight.bmp';
  } else{
    e.style.display = 'table';
    i.src = 'img/arrowDownWhite.bmp';
  }
}
```